# Postgres not looking at the right pg_hba.conf file?

Tags: psql

I recently uninstalled postgres (not sure if I did it properly. I used homebrew to uninstall it and also manually deleted whatever showed up on `locate psql` in my Terminal. Then I installed postgres.app and tried running it. However it prompts for a password (that I don't remember or don't even know exists or not) even though I went to the pg_hba.conf file I found in

```
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:~ edmundmai$ locate pg_hba
/usr/share/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
```

and changed it to trust for everything:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Am I missing something? I can't get psql to run because it prompts for a password. I'm willing to uninstall it if that fixes it.

Comment: 1) is the server running? 2) is it listening on port 5432? 3) Is it lsitening on the unix-domain socket? 4) Can you connect with psql ? (which you just deleted, LOL ;-)

Comment: yeh it's running and I believe it might still be running the vaccum, etc from when i was using the old postgres. could this be the reason why it's not working? also I found a pg_hba.conf.sample file. should i rename it to pg_hba.conf

Comment: Better copy it then rename it. You might need it again ...

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the server. Just editing pg_hba.conf isn't enough on its own.

On Ubuntu with postgres 9.1 the following worked for me

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

For more information [see the documentation on the Ubuntu help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)